# Invoke-SQLCmd Date output format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sqlcmd

I’m having a problem with a result set that I am getting from a stored procedure when running a PowerShell script (Using `Invoke-SQLCmd`) to get the results and send the output to a .csv file.

The date column is bringing back the time as well, see below. I have setup a simple example in Adventure works.

My Command is to execute a simple stored proc to just get the Top 10 From the Sales Order Header in `Adventureworks`.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "MY-PC\SQL2016" -Database "AdventureWorks2016" -Query "EXEC[AdventureWorks2016].[dbo].[SOH]" | Select-Object -Property SalesOrderID, OrderDate
```

That’s fine and I can filter out the columns I want, but I have the time `00:00:00` in the order Date Column. And I just want the date. I have googled and I am still having problems with this one. See the result set below. I need the `OrderDate` to just be the date. Not append `00:00:00` for the time.

```
SalesOrderID OrderDate 
------------ --------- 
43659 31/05/2011 00:00:00
43660 31/05/2011 00:00:00
43661 31/05/2011 00:00:00
43662 31/05/2011 00:00:00
43663 31/05/2011 00:00:00
43664 31/05/2011 00:00:00
43665 31/05/2011 00:00:00
43666 31/05/2011 00:00:00
43667 31/05/2011 00:00:00
43668 31/05/2011 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on SQL-Server 2012 or above you can use [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016) function in your stored procedure.

```
FORMAT ( value, format [, culture ] )

DECLARE @d DATETIME = GETDATE();   
SELECT FORMAT( @d, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'en-US' ) AS 'DateTime Result'
```

If you use an older version you can use CONVERT:

```
CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), @d, 103);
```

> ```
> | DateTime Result |
> | :-------------- |
> | 31/05/2011      |
>
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | 31/05/2011       |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3b410b63e0a96f4a5c417dab97355c71)*

Comment: Thanks for that, but believe it or not that does not affect the output from powershell executing the stored procedure. That still brings in the time part again.

Comment: The test is not exactly like for like. I am executing a stored procedure and trying to get a date only result.

Answer (score 1):

You must be invoking the query as following, or use `CONVERT()` as mentioned by [McNets](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/252917/185080)

```
-Q "select c1, Cast(cdate as date) as Date from TestOffline.dbo.T1"
```

Test Script

```
Create Table T1
(c1 int,
 cDate datetime)
 go

 Insert into T1 
 VALUES
 (1, '2019-11-01'),
 (2, '2019-11-02'),
 (3, '2019-11-03');
```

Result (sqlcmd):
[image]

P.S: Consider [this post](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but) and test your case, before committing with FORMAT()

Answer (score 1):

Invoke-SQLCmd brings back .Net DateTime object, not a string. PowerShell is responsible for changing it to string. Please check following link for more info about it: [DateTime struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.8)

You can do all the type conversions and formatting in PowerShell, there is an example:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[SOH]
AS
    select getdate() as  OrderDate,12 as SalesOrderID
```

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "(localdb)\ProjectsV13" -Database "SSDT Demo" -Query "exec [dbo].[SOH]" |
  foreach {[PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
    SalesOrderID = $_.SalesOrderID
    OrderDate = $_.OrderDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
    dateraw = $_.OrderDate
    }
  } | ConvertTo-Csv
```

and it will produce:

```
#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"SalesOrderID","OrderDate","dateraw"
"12","11/10/2019","11/10/2019 12:20:51 PM"
```

I added an additional dateraw column to better explain it, you will need to skip it for your export.
Also I added "converTo-Csv" because it was mentioned that it will be saved as a csv file.

Comment: Again I'm executing a stored procedure, not selecting directly from the table.

Comment: I updated the example to use a Stored Procedure matching the one you has.

Comment: Thanks Piotr, that works for me. Much appreciated! Sorry for the late reply. I needed a break :)  But good to come back and see your message. Thanks again.